# What is the simplest way to enumerable tables, views and SPs of a database

Tags: ado.net, database-schema

What is the best way to enumerate tables, views and stored procedures using ADO.NET?

Of course, one can query the master table.

Is there a simpler and more standard way? And possibly, would work on all databases.

Comment: Enumerate means a list. Please define the level of detail you need. Extended props? Permissions? Indexes and constraints?

Comment: -1 for misleading question now, when accepted answer won't give full definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Information schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) is an ANSI standard.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

Comment: For views and stored procs these will truncate. Just search this site for why: being standard doesn't make them useful

Comment: @gbn Do you mean the 4000 character limit of `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` and `VIEW_DEFINITION` columns? If @user380719 actually only needs to enumerate names of objects, it's not going to be a problem. Also I assumed that the *work on all databases* part of the question means different RDBMSs which makes information schema a good choice.

Comment: Timing sorry OP wants full def's apparently as per comment on my answer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming SQL Server you'd query [sys.objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) from your code if you want "simple "

Do you want a straight list? Or full definitions too?